# Error in Hbase Standalone mode

Tags: hadoop, hbase

My standalone hbase starts, but when i do any command in shell it goes in errors...

I have tried many solutions, nothing worked :(
Error message:

```
hbase(main):001:0> create 'emp' 'data'
16/02/08 18:42:57 ERROR zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 3 retries
16/02/08 18:42:57 WARN zookeeper.ZKUtil: hconnection Unable to set watcher on znode (/hbase/hbaseid)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1041)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:450)

.
.
.
.

My /etc/hosts:



>  127.0.0.1       localhost
>     127.0.0.1       ankit21
>     192.168.43.11   pooja
>     192.168.43.143  laptop@kalpesh
>     192.168.43.72   aditi
>     # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts(43.177)
>     ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
>     fe00::0 ip6-localnet
>     ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
>     ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
>     ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

JPS:

```
ankit@ankit21:/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.8$ jps
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
7609 HMaster
7756 Jps
```

Comment: i'm not quite sure how standalone is supposed to work, but it looks like you need to start zookeeper for it.

Comment: Can you please share your hbase-site.xml ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to start your zookeeper service. After that run **jps** command to check, you should be able to find "QuorumPeer" as a service for zookeeper.

Before starting the zookeeper service , make sure you have configured zoo.cfg in the conf directory. You need add the machine ip in zoo.cfg along with the port for zookeeper.